# Field repository in com.App.Shopping.model.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-08-30 18:09:53.081  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] com.App.Shopping.ShoppingApplication     : Starting ShoppingApplication on DESKTOP-DSCQJON with PID 4536 (D:\sarat\eclipse-workspace\Shopping.zip_expanded\Shopping\target\classes started by sarat in D:\sarat\eclipse-workspace\Shopping.zip_expanded\Shopping)
2020-08-30 18:09:53.081  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] com.App.Shopping.ShoppingApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-30 18:09:53.148  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-08-30 18:09:53.151  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-08-30 18:09:53.256  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2020-08-30 18:09:53.256  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-30 18:09:53.256  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-30 18:09:53.325  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-08-30 18:09:53.327  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-24].[localhost].[/]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-30 18:09:53.327  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 244 ms
2020-08-30 18:09:53.339  WARN 4536 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userservice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.App.Shopping.model.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ShoppingApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#71a2245c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#71a2245c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2020-08-30 18:09:53.340  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-30 18:09:53.344  INFO 4536 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-30 18:09:53.400 ERROR 4536 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field repository in com.App.Shopping.model.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'entity manager factory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entity manager factory' in your configuration.

Comment: when I start application error is getting can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I can see from stack trace that your entitymanagerfactory is not available.

Are you trying to autowire by name in your UserServiceImpl which means have you added Qualifier annotation ?

Comment: No, I didn't use the qualifier annotation